# Обращение к модели entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

```
 private client clients = new client();
    public kabinet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = clients;
       
    }

      private void vvod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cli = from client in vavlab1Entities.GetContext().clients select client;
        cli.FirstOrDefault().FIO_client = @class.FIO_client;
        cli.FirstOrDefault().number = num.Text;
        cli.FirstOrDefault().e_mail = email.Text;

         
        vavlab1Entities.GetContext().clients.AddOrUpdate(cli.FirstOrDefault());
        vavlab1Entities.GetContext().SaveChanges();
```

}

При выполнении этого кода выводит ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это значит что перечислание `cli` не содержит элементов. `FirstOrDefault` означает "первый-или-по-умолчанию", где для ссылочных типов "по умолчанию" это значит `null`.

Comment: @aepot просто проблема только с этой таблицей,  с остальными всё норм. могу спокойно обращаться к каждому элементу модели, но здесь проблема какая-то не могу понять, что не так, добавила скрин подключения к бд и скрин модели